# Error conexion base de datos

Tags: java, mysql

Quiero conectar una base de datos a java pero me da un erro y no se cual es espero me puedan ayudar

El error es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta el codigo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aqui la BD:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error te dice que no reconoce la base de datos llamada ferretería

Answer (score 1):

No se si te sirva pero en la contraseña dale un espacio a las comillas y a localhost:3306 quitale el 3306 con localhost es suficiente.

Answer (score 1):

**Acá te pongo un código de conexión de uno de mis proyectos que anda muy bien.**

Sin embargo me llamaron la atención dos cosas:

1) **Localhost:3306**, lo dejaría en **localhost**.

2) En la url de conexión declarás la DB con mayúscula Ferretería, y que yo sepa siempre que creo una nueva DB en mayúscula el motor de la DB me lo pasa a minúscula. Además en el error veo que dice ferreteria con minusculas.

Te diría que si te animás copies este código asi como está y lo pegues, dale run a lo que sea que estés haciendo, y si no va cambia a minúsculas el nombre de la DB y en la url también.

Esto último te lo digo al final porque es poco probable pero nada es imposible, creo que debe ser un tema de configuración de cada motor de DB, osea no todas actúan de esa manera.

Acá te dejo el código:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexion {

    private final static String user = "root";
    private final static String password = "";
    static Connection connection = null;

    public static Connection getConexion() throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ferreteria", user, password);

        return connection;
    }
}
```

Te dejo también un ejemplo por las dudas nomás como algo anexo, una insercción a DB, llamando a ésa conexión directamente desde la clase, ya que es un método estático.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import com.soa.dao.Conexion;

public class ClientController {

    /* Método para insertar a la DB */
    public static void exampleInsertQuery(String name, String lastname) {
        Connection connection = null;
        /* Intentamos conectarnos */
        try {
            connection = Conexion.getConexion();

            /* Si no es nula que entre al método que nos facilita realizar la insercción */
            if (connection != null) {
                PreparedStatement ps;
                String sql = "INSERT INTO clients(name, lastname) VALUES(?,?)";
                ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setString(1, name);
                ps.setString(2, lastname);
                ps.executeUpdate();
                ps.close();
                System.out.println("Query executed");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Connection appears to be null");
            }
        } catch (Exception error) {
            System.out.println("Cannot even connect");
            error.getMessage();
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```